# Block function call from WndProc handler function in C#

Tags: c#, synchronization, nonblocking

I have code in C# where Window is getting messages (images from GigE camera). In function handler I call another function to do some processing on the image I get from message. This processing can take more time than time between next message I get. I would like to use some nice mechanism to ignore messages until processing will be done. I could simply write:

```
bool is_processing = false;

void HandleUeyeMessage(int wParam, int lParam) 
{
   frame = getNewFrame();

   if(!is_processing) {
      doProcessing(frame);
   } else non-blocking ignore 
}

void doProcessing(frame f)
{
    is_processing = true;
    // some processing work...
    is_processing = false;
    return;
}
```

but I want to use some synchronization mechanism, but I don't really know what to use because this is not generally threading thing...

Comment: If possible, you really shouldn't process images in the WndProc handler IMO.

Comment: well, I have sample code from camera suplier and he acquires image in in that way, so where could I manage processing if not here? However, aquisition works fine.

Comment: well.. ok.. sorry.. I've just tried to capture this in openCV by Capture class.. and it works... However if somebody could answer my question it would be nice for future

Comment: This just isn't a real problem.  You cannot receive another message at the same time your UI thread is busy processing the original message.  So there's nothing to ignore.

Comment: Not really, messages are coming one by another and not waiting if ones is finished so this handler method is being invoked independently. I even tried to put sleep() into processing function, before this function I put MessageBox and messageBoxes were showing one by another.. that means also processing function could be invoked too many times

Answer (score 0):

you cannot ignore messages in a single thread- they will be queued and processed when your app is able to respond. You can use worker thread with some basic synchronization.

```
BackgroundWorker _worker=new BackgroundWorker();

void OnMessage(int lparam, int wparam)
{
    frame frame=GetFrame();
   if(!_worker.IsBusy)
        _worker.RunWorkerAsync(frame);
}

void DoWork(object sender,DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    //do processing
}
```

Comment: I dont want to block messages, I just dont want to invoke processing function if it is still working from previous call. Background worker is to slow for this purpose, rather ThreadPool, but this is not threding thing IMO.. so I just want to ignore frame if previous frame is being processed

Comment: You can't do it with a single thread and processing flags, because any new messages will be delayed till the processing finishes, and then the processing flag is false. All messages will be processed, one after the another. With a background thread you can still get messages, and decide if to process them. if `_worker.IsBusy`, nothing happens and the message is ignored.

Comment: ok so volatile flag is the best solution I guess because I'a afraid if worker wouldnt be too slow.. thx

Comment: Creating a new thread is more expensive than using a thread pool.